# Como puedo mandar a llamar un modal con booststrap o algun div con un cuadro de texto?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo al siguiente tabla, la parte de los botones al presionarlos consultan un dato y se vuelve a pintar la tabla con el dato, lo que necesito es que si no exite el dato de la consulta pueda ingresar la cantidad manualmente.
Y pensaba hacerlo en un modal pero no se como mandarlo a llamar.
[image: TABLA DE DATOS]

```
$n_f1_1 = function(){        

      console.log(arguments[0]);
      console.log(arguments[1]);

      $.post("pages/reporte/nuevo/post/nutriente/f1_n.php", {ID: arguments[0],ID_NUTRIENTE: arguments[1]}, function(mensaje) {
        $("#T").html(mensaje);
     });

      $('#paso3').load('pages/reporte/nuevo/post/nutriente/refrsh_table.php');

    };
```

Esta es la funcion con la que se suben y se refresca la tabla.
Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Quizás, si es sólo un dato, trabajar con modales, no sea lo más práctico, te recomendaría, que le des una mirada a la librería [**SweetAlert2**](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) que es espectacular para lo que buscas hacer!

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo.
Se me ocurre ponerlo en un botón y llamarlo con jQuery, por ejemplo

```
<button onclick="ShowModal()" class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Titulo</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function ShowModal(){
     $('#myModal').modal('show')
  }
</script>
```

Nota: Estoy usando bootstrap 4

Más información en el sitio oficial de bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Hugo, siempre es recomendable evitar el uso de `onclick` y demas funciones en las etiquetas html, más aún, si estas incluyendo una librería como jQuery, que una de sus funcionalidades más potentes es, justamente, la selección de elementos

Comment: Gracias por la observación, como dije hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Pero sí, tienes razón.